# Error onchange (function) is not defined at HTMLSelectElement.function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner in programming and today I need your help!(please :'()

I want to create a survey,so I begin to code and a error appear and I search a lot in internet but no solution.

There are my html and js codes.

```js
/*the code isn't finish, this error block me(code name is sur.js*/
let choi;
let choix1 = 1;
let choix2 = 1;
let choix3 = 1;
function submit(){
console.log(choi);
}
function changer(){
getElementById('survey');
choi= sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
console.log(choi);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Robotale v8 : surveys</title>
<link rel="icon" href="https://www.mediafire.com/convkey/a940/qp7vky5trrp8hmzzg.jpg"/>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#000000">
<br>
<a href="Index.html">
<img src="https://www.mediafire.com/convkey/6586/bb0x08ff0tvjhepzg.jpg" onclick="redirection()"/>
</a>
<br>
<font face= "Verdana" size="4" color="#3399ff">The Robotale Website is here for your Robotale time!!!</p>
<br>
<p>Surveys:</p>
<br>
<form>
<label for="survey">Your feedback about this website!!!How do you like it?</label>
<select id="survey" name="survey" type="datalist" onchange="changer();">
<datalist id="surveys">
<option value="No">Nope!!!</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes!!!</option>
<option value="liv">THIS WEBSITE IS MY LIFE IF YOU DELETE IT I WILL DIE!!!(calm down please)</option>
</datalist>
</form>
<a href="Index.html">link to principal page</a>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Send your feedback" id="food" onclick="submit()">
<br>
<script src"sur.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: You gave an incomplete js code.

Comment: please can you explain?yeah the code is incomplete but explain please

Comment: ok i gave you the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify an incomplete call to the selector - `getElementById('survey');`. The rule is to use the `document`, and you need to write like this - `document.getElementById('survey');`.

Next, you have an undefined variable `sel`, and I mean that this variable is filled with data from `document.getElementById('survey');`. It turned out like this - `let sel = document.getElementById('survey');`

Now run this code and try to select a value from the dropdown list. There are no errors.

That is how it should be?

```js
/*the code isn't finish, this error block me(code name is sur.js*/
let choi;
let choix1 = 1;
let choix2 = 1;
let choix3 = 1;
function submit(){
console.log(choi);
}
function changer(){
let sel = document.getElementById('survey');
choi= sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
console.log(choi);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Robotale v8 : surveys</title>
<link rel="icon" href="https://www.mediafire.com/convkey/a940/qp7vky5trrp8hmzzg.jpg"/>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#000000">
<br>
<a href="Index.html">
<img src="https://www.mediafire.com/convkey/6586/bb0x08ff0tvjhepzg.jpg" onclick="redirection()"/>
</a>
<br>
<font face= "Verdana" size="4" color="#3399ff">The Robotale Website is here for your Robotale time!!!</p>
<br>
<p>Surveys:</p>
<br>
<form>
<label for="survey">Your feedback about this website!!!How do you like it?</label>
<select id="survey" name="survey" type="datalist" onchange="changer();">
<datalist id="surveys">
<option value="No">Nope!!!</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes!!!</option>
<option value="liv">THIS WEBSITE IS MY LIFE IF YOU DELETE IT I WILL DIE!!!(calm down please)</option>
</datalist>
</form>
<a href="Index.html">link to principal page</a>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Send your feedback" id="food" onclick="submit()">
<br>
<script src"sur.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: yes sorry I thought the surveys can be made with JS but no now i learned php tyhe problem is solved thanks!

Comment: @LeQuaranteQuatre, hello. I was glad to try to help you :)